# Integrating a remote Swift Package that has local Swift Packages: how to avoid invalidManifestFormat errors?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

The situation:

I have a Swift Package, call it `lib`. `lib` lives in its own repository. In `lib`'s repository, there are a bunch of local Packages; that is, these are packages that are defined, in lib, using the local-path dependency format, `.package(path: "CursorPackage"),` and whatnot.

All of this is fine as long as I'm locally importing `lib` into my actual application repository. The moment I try to import `lib` into my repo using SPM's remote options, which is obviously the way to go for doing things with CI, it throws the following error:

> invalidManifestFormat("'CursorPackage' is not a valid path for path-based dependencies; use relative or absolute path instead.")

This error persists whether I use `CursorPackage` or `./CursorPackage`. Obviously I don't want to try to use an absolute path, because I'm on CI, so that would involve either hard-coding things or ingesting an environment variable somehow that contains `PWD`.

What am I missing? This seems like it should just work. Is this just a bug in SPM that I should be reporting to Apple?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't intended to be possible. If you look at the 5th bullet in the Proposed Solution section of the local packages proposal (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0201-package-manager-local-dependencies.md) it says that it's not intended for a remote package to be allowed to depend on a local package.

I expect its because there's the possibility that you could have both a versioned package with a given name and a local package with the same name; if so how would SPM resolve the conflict?

It is unfortunate though since allowing this would allow for more options in how people organize their packages, I agree.